# Solution Files with MSBuild With TFS2012 on large projects

Tags: msbuild

I came across this article and wondered if there are any changes in this for TFS2012 and .Net4.5 version of MSBuild?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx#id0100082

Did they make solutions more managable for large projects?

Or is compiling .csproj files still best practice using traversal targets ?

Double B

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean building a large number of projects from a solution file.

Solutions in VS2012 are the same as they have always been in the sense that they are only containers for projects. If you are automating your build using TFS then you would use windows workflow to create build definitions. However, you can still create your own msbuild project file and create the order of projects to build if you need to. MSBuild techinally does not know what a solution file is and so it is converted during build time for you.

The article you referenced is from 2009 , but is still good if you want to dive into msubild project files and have complete control of what your build does.